# I imprisoned my wife: if I exile her, will we be still married?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Since my wife had the annoying habit of murdering my spymasters, I've decided it was time for her to experience the dungeons.

Now I've noticed I've basically four options:

- execute her
- exile her
- release her
- do nothing

Considering she hasn't great stats and does't bring any alliance, I think getting rid of her might be the best idea… so, how do I do that?

I.e., if I just execute her, will I get some weird penalty? If I exile her, will we still count as married? Other options?

PS:

- it was a **righteous imprisonment**
- **we are both cathar**
- I'm 51, IIRC
- I might also be a lover with her, and with another courtier (I don't remember this exactly, but if someone points out this is important, I'll give an update)

Comment: If you execute her your in-laws will be unhappy. Are your in-laws important people?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia The 'title sounds weird out of context' pattern is a recurring meme of Arqade, see for instance http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2196/71227.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes.

The marriage lasts until death do you part. So either you encourage the death part, or if you are good friends with the Pope (or your preferred religious head), you can ask for him to annul the marriage ... however since you are Cathar, that is not an option.

This is a historically correct depiction of royal marriages in medieval Europe. Lots of regents lived apart from their wives for various reasons. To put it in in-game terms, the good [Henry VIII of England installed an anti-pope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_England#Secession_from_Rome), because the Catholic Pope wouldn't grant him more divorces.

However, a spouse in exile should lower her plot power, and definitely the fertility rate. (I have no exact numbers, please educate me). Since she is also your lover (*sigh*), I guess there is still the chance of producing babies, however.

Note, that while she is imprisoned, she can't participate in any plots.

As a sidenote, if she's such a fantastic schemer, and she likes killing of your spymasters ... why don't you install her? Obviously she wants the job. :)

Comment: I didn't install her for two reasons: 1. since she's also my wife I would only get her bonus once instead of twice (as both wife and council member) 2. she seems to be able to kill them, but her value is actually quite low (9) compared to the others who got the job. If it wasn't a game with visible stats, based on her performances, I would have, but since I _know_ she's not as good as it seems, it would be pointless (right? or are there hidden stats or sorts, or something I didn't think about?).

Comment: @Lohoris 9 is definitely not bad, there might be 3-4 people in your whole kingdom that have a higher score. Though of course, for your council you usually want the best, not just good.

Comment: Henry didn't install an antipope, he had the Church of England secede from Rome. If he'd said that Cranmer wasn't just independent from Rome, but actually the real Pope and all the Roman Catholics in the world had to follow him, *then* he'd have installed an antipope.

Comment: @JonHanna An antipope doesn't need any substantial amount of the Church to recognise him as being Pope. The antipopes worth talking about typically convince some section of the Church that he is the real Pope, but hardly all.

Comment: @JamesHaug they do all claim that they should have such support though. Henry VIII made no such claim.

Comment: @JonHanna Sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

She will remain your wife.

I would not recommend exiling her since that puts her beyond your easy reach. Either hope she dies in jail (she'll probably complain after a bit giving you the option of dumping her into even worse conditions until she croaks) or start a plot to assassinate her.

Execution will bring penalties. Killing her by plot is risky if discovered but if you can get enough plot power the risk will be small.